# How to display all taxonomy terms as links and point them to nid in views

Tags: views

1. I created a taxonomy vocabulary and terms.

[image]

2. I created a content type with the taxonomy.

[image]

3. I added contents.

[image]

4. I would like to create a views block that will display all the taxonomy terms as links as well as each link should point to its NID.

[image]

For my views block:

I selected the taxonomy field.

I selected "Rendered taxonomy terms" in Formatter.

Click the Taxonomy field.

Selected output this field as link.

Entered node/[nid] as links path.

It did not work.  Also, links are not pointed to NID. Can you please help how to edit the views settings?

---

Views settings:
[image]

Comment: [Why are you yelling at us](http://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/720title.jpg)? You think yelling makes me want to answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for writing it in caps. I had a long day today. I simply lost my mind. I did edit my post. Hopefully, you will accept it this time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the basis of your View is a node, you can add a field to your View: `Content: Link` (which is a link to the node of the View's row) and use the `Rewrite results > Rewrite the output of this field` with the contents of the taxonomy term (if I'm not mistaken `[field_cities_we_serve1]`).

Comment: I added views settings and the result above. Please advise if I followed your instruction correctly. Also, I am creating views block instead of views page.

Comment: @Drupol `I only see the cities` Are you u sure those nodes are tagged with the States? double check to make sure the term reference field is not empty, because they should be showing up.

Comment: I made a mistake. I did not have nodes for states. Now, I added nodes for states and I have 6 nodes. I see them in this order on a column(VA, MD, cities....). How to group them by states? When I click link, it takes me to taxonomy/term/x. Instead, how to link to NID?